# What does the "System setting" option do for the Theme preference?

Tags: support, profile-page, dark-mode

With the new theme mode, there are 3 options:

- Light
- System setting
- Dark

[image]

What does the middle option, "System setting", do? For me, nothing changes; it looks the same as `Light`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It will check what your OS / browser settings are. For example on mac you can setup dark theme.

So if your system is running dark theme, then it will use dark mode. If it's not using it then it will use light mode.

Comment: This is present on recent versions of all major operating systems afaik, [Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp825.png), Android, most Linux desktop environments, etc support it too. Note that this is usually an OS setting, not a browser setting, but the browser must support it and will follow the OS setting.

Comment: @ErikA yes i meant that too, updated the answer.

Comment: Much more clear with the answer, but it would be good if there was some explanation or a tooltip

Comment: On Opera on MacOS with system-wide dark mode enabled, the SO "system setting" option doesn't work, so an explanation would indeed be useful.

Comment: Maybe that's why they're calling it a Beta....

Comment: Note for desktop Linux users: on my Xubuntu 18.04 I have to use `--force-dark-mode` option for `chromium-browser` to let StackOverflow see system mode as dark. Additionally passing `--enable-features=WebUIDarkMode` makes Chromium settings pages also dark. See the [relevant post at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1160681/113421).

Answer (score 2):

On many smartphones and modern OSes, there is an option to change between dark and light mode.

**Here is the option in iOS:**

[image: iOS settings]

If you select `System setting` on Stack Overflow then Stack Overflow will choose light/dark theme depending on what your device's current theme is.

Comment: It's not just phones, modern computer OSes support it as well.